# Inserting duplicates with nhibernate

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, nhibernate

I need to duplicate an object and all of its children, what I'm doing now is retrieve the object, make a deep clone and put all ids to 0 (parent and children) and save it back to the DB, but the original object gets modified in the DB. Is there a way to make it simpler?

Thanks in advance for the help.
Ariel.

**EDIT**

I'm using serialization to get a deep copy of the object, but the strangest thing is this. I'm serializing the object and I save it in a file, then I deserialize the object and put ids to 0, then I make some operations for some values of the parent and children to change the original values, I save everything fine, but the problem is when I flush the session. for example I have this:

ORIGINAL:

```
Parent
  IdParent = 1
  Name = "Parent"
Child 1
  IdChild = 1
  IdParent = 1
  Name = "Child 1"
```

MODIFIED:

```
Parent = 0
  Name = "Parent"
Child 1
  IdChild = 0
  IdParent = null
  Name = "Child 1 modified"
```

The parent has a collection of type IList When I save the values everythings's fine, but when the flush is called this extra statement is executed:

UPDATE Child SET IdParent = null WHERE IdParent = 1

And the original data in the DB is modified like this

CHILD TABLE:

```
IdChild     | IdParent    | Name
--------------------------------------
1           | Null        | "Child 1"
2           | 2           | "Child 1 modified"
```

Any idea???

Thanks a lot for any help.
Ariel

**EDIT 2**

The methods I'm using

SERIALIZE:

```
Stream archivo = File.Create(rutaArchivo);
BinaryFormatter serializador = new BinaryFormatter();
serializador.Serialize(archivo, objetoASerializar);
archivo.Close();
```

DESERIALIZE:

```
Stream archivo = File.OpenRead(rutaArchivo);
BinaryFormatter serializador = new BinaryFormatter();
T objetoDeserializado = (T)serializador.Deserialize(archivo);
archivo.Close();
```

Comment: Can you show us your serialization/deserialization code?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I think if original object gets modified, you "deep copy" is not so deep, I guess you copy collections from original object. There are 2 general way's i think you can make this:

- Create .NET object copy this can be done in different ways, modify you clone code to make it really deep copy clone, serialize you object and deserialize it to make a clone, try to use AutoMapper to create clone (not sure if it can map object to itself thus creating copy) but if it can it will copy you collections the proper way.
- Do it the DB SQL style: INSERT INTO Table (SELECT * FROM TABLE where Id=@id)